# Dynamic argument and type checking in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am looking into a best way how to do argument validation in Javascript. I like Flow but I am interested in easy run-time checking with meaningful exceptions.

So far I was able to find only assertion libraries for testing purposes. Is it ok to use those in normal production code or is preferable to code my own assertion library ?

Comment: Why do you not compose your own tests for argument type? Why is a library necessary?